# Is it possible to measure L-cysteine amino acid levels in the body?

Tags: nutrition, supplement, amino-acids

The supplement [N-ACETYL CYSTEINE (NAC)](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5241507/) is increasingly popular among patients suffering from the mental and physical issues [NAC claims to improve](https://www.healthline.com/nutrition/nac-benefits).

However, the article also states "*it is found in most high-protein foods, such as chicken, turkey, yogurt, cheese, eggs, sunflower seeds and legumes*".

If a patient wants to know if they are deficient or need to add more:

- Is there a direct test to measure L-cysteine amino acid levels in the
  body?
- If not, is there an indirect test to measure correlated amino acids (such as methionine and serine)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Measuring the concentration of amino acids "in the body" is a bit difficult. Your body is made up of lots of cells and organs, each one of which exists in a constant state of flux and contains many proteins and amino acids.

Assuming perhaps that you meant "in the blood", then yes, such kits do exist -- e.g. this enzyme-linked spectrophotomeric assay --  https://www.antibodies-online.com/kit/1503021/Cysteine+ELISA+Kit/ -- but it costs €642,85 (+€40 shipping and 22% VAT) for 96 tests, and requires a molecular biology laboratory to use.

The only commonly performed similar tests I am aware of are whole plasma amino acid counts, commonly performed on infants to look for inborn errors of metabolism -- i.e. specific birth defects of metabolism. You can find an example US Hospital page [here](https://www.ucsfbenioffchildrens.org/tests/003361.html) that contains the reference range for each amino acid.

Comment: Thanks. Open to any type of test. Looks like the blood test you linked includes that. Guess the question is will the blood test be a good reflection of it, relative to the desired health benefit ?

Comment: You could do a lot cheaper for the blood test: find an enzyme specific for cysteine which uses i.e. NAD or NADP as another substrate and measure the difference in absorption, Lambert-Beer will give you the concentration. Photometer is 300 USD, enzyme cost may vary